# MPDF - large table

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am generating table with mPDF, that is larger than 1 page (about 4-8 pages) and a have problem, that some rows are separated on their own pages. How to join them to one big table?

Comment: Examples suggest that using tables across multiple pages is possible with that library. http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_tables.pdf . What are you wondering about exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with `colspan`.

I had only 2 columns but the header was with `colspan = 3`.

When I put it to `colspan = 2`, problem resolved.

Comment: Had exact same problem, stumbled on it for hour, tnx much !